# Run ONE app as admin w/o request

Tags: windows-7, permissions

My bro wants to run frozen throne (warcraft 3 expansion, blizzard) and he cant play online (battle.net) without running as an admin.

He figured out how to make the shortcut launch it as admin but it always ask him for permission. How do we change it so it no longer ask permission for that shortcut/game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warcraft III is likely asking for administrative privileges so that it can download maps from other players on Battle.net. You can get around this by giving control of the program folder to the user(s) who will be running the game.

[image: obligatory screenshot]

- Navigate to *C:\Program Files* (or wherever you installed the game).
- Right click on the *Warcraft III* folder and choose properties.
- Click on the *Security* tab.
- Click on the *Edit...* button halfway down the window.
- Find your user name in the pane labeled *Group or user names:* and click it.
- In the lower pane (*Permissions for Users*), click every box in the *Allow* column.
- Click *OK* twice to close the properties windows.

You may now run Warcraft III free of annoying UAC prompts.

Note that even after you have done this, you may still get prompts for admin permission when a patch has been released. I'm not sure how much you can do about that, because it's not the game asking for permission. Each patch comes in the form of a new program that Windows hasn't seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Elevator](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/05/16/ignore-uac-for-specific-programs.aspx) a shot. It will add an "Elevate Me" context menu item that surpasses UAC dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the shortcut and choose "Properties," then:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that still bring up a UAC prompt?

Comment: I'd turned UAC off so I had to re-enable to test. You're right, and as I re-read you original question, I see that your brother already knows how to do what I've proposed. My bad.